# Accessing json file from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, cross-domain, jsonp

I have two websites namely:

```
www.siteone.com 
www.sitetwo.com
```

Now I have to display data in `www.siteone.com` by getting data via script from `www.sitetwo.com`
Since I have to get particular data, I am passing variable from `www.siteone.com` to `www.sitetwo.com` like this:

```
 //script in www.siteone.com
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.$vars = {
            id:"form"
        };
</script>
```

In `www.sitetwo.com`, I have the following script:

```
//script in www.sitetwo.com
<script type="text/javascript">
 var k = window.$vars.id;
$("#form").dform("http://www.sitetwo.com/"+k+'.json', function(data) {

          this
          data

        });
</script>
```

Here the value "id" that I am passing from siteone to site two is received by the script correctly. But I cannot open form.json file due to crossdomain. The following error is thrown:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.sitetwo.com/form.json. Origin http://www.siteone.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I access form.json from `www.siteone.com`

Comment: jsonp is the answer. You need to find a way to use jsonp with that `dform` ajax call.

Comment: dform is a function from another script loaded in that page.How can we effectively use jsonp in these cases??

Comment: i haven't used that dform script. With jquery ajax you can easily use jsonp by setting dataType to jsonp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can send an additional header from server side script.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.sitetwo.com");
```

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: It involves configuring server. But can't we use this header directly in scripts??

Answer (score 0):

Browser standarts does not allow you to load JSON from another domain because of [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)